# Ionic 3/Angular 4 - Pair of input-button - Set input value dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have a situation: A form, with multiple inputs and a button after input:

Template:

```
<ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Test</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="teste" [ngModel]="teste" type="text"></ion-input>
          <button large type="button" (click)="input_to_voice($event)" clear ion-button icon-only item-end>
            <ion-icon name="mic"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-item>
```

When I tap the button I want to set the value calculated by function automatically to the input:

```
 input_to_voice(event, value) {

    //here I wanted to get a reference to the input value, but I'm stuck
    console.log(event.target.parentElement.parentElement);

    let options = {
      language: "en-GB"
    };

    // Start the recognition process
    this.speechRecognition.startListening(options)
      .subscribe(
        (matches: Array<string>) => console.log(matches),
        (onerror) => console.log('error:', onerror)
      )
  }
```

So:
For a single input is easy to do this. But how can I can get the multiple input references from `$event` and set the calculated values automatically?

(Ex: press the third input button and that button will "know" for which input will set the value)

Comment: you are already using ngModel.  just access the data with this.teste1 and this.teste2 or however you decide to name the two.

Comment: You are using a reactive form apparently. Use that :)

Comment: And how my function knows from what corresponding input button was the request made?

Comment: You pass the formControl to your function. Also consider choosing either template driven form (ngModel) or reactive form (form control) as having two bindings isn't really recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the variable you want to use in the **ngModel**:

```
private teste: string;
```

If you need two different values for the inputs, you just need to create another variable with a different name.

And then you can access it inside the method like this:

```
input_to_voice() {
    console.log(this.teste);
}
```

Remember that using the **ngModel** any changes you make on your variable will reflect in your *html* or *ts* file.

**Edit**

Then you could try to do like this:

Change the input tag:

```
<ion-input type="text" #teste></ion-input>
```

Then make this import:

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

And add this line inside of your class:

```
@ViewChild('teste') input;
```

Then you could access the input value from the method like this:

```
input_to_voice() {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to do this.
I want to input_to_voice() to know automatically from what input-button group receive the request without making variables for all inputs. I thought I can get the input reference from $event, but I don't know how to set input value from that.

Comment: I think I understand. I wouldn't recommend to do it like this, but I edited my answer. Hope this could help.

Comment: And for multiple inputs, will need to set to every one different tags? 
" wouldn't recommend to do it like this" - can you give some arguments?
Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. You'll have to define different tags. Look, this way you're getting directly from the DOM, and you can't have much control that way. ilI would use Reactive Forms to treat the inputs rules and values.

Comment: I already use reactive forms, but I can't understand at what you refer based on my context.